# how to check a variable is having nextline or not in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a wrote one js program so that it will accept the user input from a textfield and then it the program automatically make that user input in to the screen like a status in fb.
in that if i gave that input and when it is displaying the next line sentence is appended to the before sentence.

how can i check that one and correct that mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste your code here.

Answer (score 1):

In a very simple way, this problem can be solved using the indexOf method.

```
var text = textarea.innerHTML;
if(text.indexOf('\n') !== -1) {
  // the text contains a new line
}
```

The indexOf method returns the index of the expression or -1 if it isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $("#theTextArea").val();
var match = /.*\r|.*\n/.exec(text);
if (match) {
    // Found .. the text area has a sentence already.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HT92R/9/)

```
var x = "Some text\n here";
var patt1 = /\n/;
alert(x);
if(x.search(patt1) > 0)  
    alert("New line character present");
else
    alert("New line character not present");
```